# Getting error while using List<>

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a `List<>`, but I get the following error:

> Cannot implicity convert type 'SpawnGroup' to 'List'.

Here is my code:

```
private List<SpawnGroup> spawnsByMapId = new List<SpawnGroup>();
```

and the error occurs here:

```
List<SpawnGroup> mapSpawnGroups = spawnsByMapId[worldId];//Error
```

What do I need to do?

**SOLVED**
im using Dictionary `private Dictionary<int, List<SpawnGroup>> spawnsByMapId = new Dictionary<int, List<SpawnGroup>>();`

for make this code work

```
List<SpawnGroup> mapSpawnGroups = spawnsByMapId[worldId];//this working now
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do with the line on which you have an error. How do you expect element of the list to be equal to List<T>

Comment: This is not clear. What are you trying to do? Adding a `SpawnGroup`element to `mapSpawnGroups` or all `spawnsByMapId`to `mapSpawnGroups`?

Comment: I need to add spawnsByMapId with worldId int value to mapSpawnGroups

Comment: Then you must do `mapSpawnGroups.Add(spawnsByMapId[worldId]);`

Answer (score 4):

by `[worldId]` you access a single `SpawnGroup` object out of your `List<SpawnGroup>`...

```
SpawnGroup mapSpawnGroups = spawnsByMapId[worldId];//No Error
```

**Edit for adding:** You asked how to add this item to another list, there are two ways:

```
// 1. Create a new object, add item later
var mapSpawnGroups = new List<SpawnGroup>() 
mapSpawnGroups.Add(spawnsByMapId[worldId]) 
// 2. or this way, create new object and add item directly
var mapSpawnGroups = new List<SpawnGroup>() { spawnsByMapId[worldId] }
```

**EDIT:** just thought about it ^^ ...If your  `[SpawnGroup]` class looks like this:

```
public class SpawnGroup : List<SpawnGroup>
```

then it would work ;) though I don't think this is what u asked for

Comment: There are anyway to add spawnsByMapId[worldId] into List<SpawnGroup>?

Comment: If you want to add an item you will have to `mapSpawnGroups.Add(spawnsByMapId[worldId])` or  `List<SpawnGroup> mapSpawnGroups = new List<SpawnGroup>() { spawnsByMapId[worldId] }` I changed the answer - @NguyễnTrường

Answer (score 0):

[@TripleEEE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6952884/tripleeee)'s answer is correct.

Basically, you need to understand what a List is. Just imagine a List as a dynamic array where it can change its length, insert/delete elements etc. Referencing an element in a List is the same as in an array. Also, List is a template class, that is, the type of its element is not fixed. With this in mind,

```
private List<SpawnGroup> spawnsByMapId = new List<SpawnGroup>(10);
```

is analogous to

```
private SpawnGroup[] spawnsByMapId = new SpawnGroup[10];
```

With the latter, you know you can't do the following (assuming worldId is an integer type):

```
SpawnGroup[] spawnsGroup = spawnsByMapId[worldId]; // Error
```

But, you can get its element by

```
SpawnGroup spawnsGroup = spawnsByMapId[worldId];
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved by using Dictionary

```
private Dictionary<int, List<SpawnGroup>> spawnsByMapId = new Dictionary<int, List<SpawnGroup>>();
```

and now I can use the code without error:

```
List<SpawnGroup> mapSpawnGroups = spawnsByMapId[worldId]; // This works
```

Comment: By this you *set* (not *add* )your whole list of SpawnGroups into your `mapSpawnGroups` - if you want to do this you could have used: `.AddRange(spawnsByMapId)` for adding or just ` mapSpawnGroups = spawnsByMapId`

Comment: Thanks for your sugguest. @TripleEEE