# Getting KeyNotFoundException while using Dictionary

Tags: c#

Im using a `Dictionary`

```
private Dictionary<int, List<SpawnGroup>> spawnsByMapId 
             = new Dictionary<int, List<SpawnGroup>>();
```

But I get an error 'KeyNotFoundException' when using this code:

```
List<SpawnGroup> a = spawnsByMapId[worldId];//KeyNotFoundException
if (a == null)
{
     // do something with a
}
```

I want to do dictionary `spawnsByMapId[worldId]` Add to `List<SpawnGroup>` but if key of `spawnsByMapId[worldId]` does not exist then `return null` into the `List<SpawnGroup>`

So what do I need to do?

Comment: Well that's simply not what the `Dictionary<,>` indexer does - did you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx)? Use `TryGetValue` instead.

Comment: Ack, you solved it the bad way. Also, you dont need to update the question with how you solved it - thats what answers are for!

Comment: @Jamiec thanks for suggest xD

Comment: Related to : [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40737396/getting-error-while-using-list/40737726)

Answer (score 4):

Either using [`ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) with a ternary operator:

```
List<SpawnGroup> a = spawnByMapId.ContainsKey(worldId) ? spawnsByMapId[worldId] : null;
if(a != null)
{
     // a is not null here.
}
```

or [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<SpawnGroup> a = null;
if(spawnsByMapId.TryGetValue(worldId, out a))
{
    // a is not null here.
}
```

It sounds (from comments) like you're trying to do this:

```
List<SpawnGroup> a = null;
if(!spawnsByMapId.TryGetValue(worldId, out a))
{
    // add new record to spawnsByMapId
    spawnsByMapId.Add(worldId, new List<SpawnGroup>());
}
```

Comment: I prefer `.TryGetValue()`, cause it makes just one lookup, instead of two.

Comment: @Oliver totally agree, but put both for completeness.

Comment: @Oliver But i need to check if `return null` will add `data` into the `dictionary`.

Comment: So, If im using `.TryGetValue()` to check if `return null` i will need use `else {}` to im prefer using @Jamiec the first solution for sort code. xD

Comment: @NguyễnTrường or just use `(!spawnsByMapId.TryGetValue(...))` - no need for an else if you reverse the logic. See update.

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec 
This is what i need todo:

`//put to map spawns
            List<SpawnGroup> mapSpawnGroups = null;
            if (!spawnsByMapId.TryGetValue(worldId, out mapSpawnGroups))
            {
                mapSpawnGroups = new List<SpawnGroup>();
                spawnsByMapId.Add(worldId, mapSpawnGroups);
            }
            mapSpawnGroups.Add(spawnGroup);`

Answer (score 0):

My *standard pattern* if you like to use nested dictionaries is this one:

```
List<SpawnGroup> groups;

if(!dict.TryGetValue(myId, out groups))
{
    groups = new List<SpawnGroup>();
    dict.Add(myId, groups);
}

// further proceed with groups
```